# filter array of objects by another true flagged subkey object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter

I'm trying to filter list of objects by another object here example

```
// the list need to be filtered 
const list  = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Loraine Mueller",
    "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/BroumiYoussef/128.jpg",
    "status": "offline",
    "language": "German",
    "rating": 4,
    "reviews": 4308
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Katarina Kilback",
    "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/dvdwinden/128.jpg",
    "status": "online",
    "language": "German",
    "rating": 5,
    "reviews": 8484
  }
]
```

```
const filterBy = {
 status: {
  online: true,
  offline: false
 },
 language: {
  english: true,
  german: false
 }
}
```

the idea to implement _filterList(list, filterBy): return filtered list with online and german items

What i tried

```
const _filter = (rows, filterBy) => {
  let result = [...rows];
  Object.keys(filterBy)
    .map(key => result = [...result.filter(row => filterBy[key].includes(row[key]))]);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: please add the wanted result. what means `true`/`false` in the filter?

Comment: please specify which filter do you want.

Comment: true values which is ["german"] and ["online"]

Comment: do you want to use `filterBy` or `filters` or both and how are they connected to the resutl and each other? please add the wanted result.

Comment: Your snippet does not match your spec and confused the answers. Please remove it or edit to conform to the spec.

Comment: done sorry for confusing you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want the results where the given filter key is any of the values in the list, a combination of `filter`/`every`/`includes` does the trick:

```
const list = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Loraine Mueller",
    status: "offline",
    language: "German",
    rating: 4,
    reviews: 4308,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Katarina Kilback",
    status: "online",
    language: "German",
    rating: 5,
    reviews: 8484,
  },
];

function filterBy(list, filters) {
  return list.filter(ent =>
    Object.keys(filters).every(filterKey =>
      filters[filterKey].includes(ent[filterKey]),
    ),
  );
}

console.log(
  filterBy(list, {
    status: ["online"],
    language: ["German"],
  }),
);
```

outputs Katarina only.

**EDIT:** Based on the comment, we also need to transform the filter object into this shape. Sure thing.

```
function transformFilters(filterBy) {
  const transformedFilters = {};
  for (var key in filterBy) {
    const values = [];
    for (var value in filterBy[key]) {
      if (filterBy[key][value]) {
        values.push(value);
      }
    }
    if (values.length) {
      transformedFilters[key] = values;
    }
  }
  return transformedFilters;
}

console.log(
  transformFilters({
    status: {
      online: true,
      offline: false,
    },
    language: {
      english: true,
      german: false,
    },
  }),
);
```

outputs

```
{ status: [ 'online' ], language: [ 'english' ] }
```

Comment: filters object should be like this  `  status: {
    online: true,
    offline: false
  },
  language: {
    english: false,
    german: true
  }`

Answer (score 0):

I use my `ruleOut` function for filtering objects based on **specific unwanted property values.** I'd like to leave my method here.

```
function ruleOut(arr, filterObj, applyAllFilters=true) {    
    return arr.filter( row => {            
        for (var field in filterObj) {
            var val = row[field];
            if (val) {                    
                if (applyAllFilters && filterObj[field].indexOf(val) > -1) return false;                
                else if (!applyAllFilters) {                        
                    return filterObj[field].filter(function(filterValue){ 
                        return (val.indexOf(filterValue)>-1);
                    }).length == 0;                 
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

Say you have a list of actors like this:

```
let actors = [
  {userName:"Mary", job:"star", language:"Turkish"},
  {userName:"John", job:"actor", language:"Turkish"},
  {userName:"Takis", job:"star", language:"Greek"},
  {userName:"Joe", job:"star", language:"Turkish"},
  {userName:"Bill", job:"star", language:"Turkish"}
];
```

and you would like to find all actors that are rated as Holywood stars, their nationality should not be one of 'English', 'Italian', 'Spanish', 'Greek', plus their name would not be one of 'Mary', 'Joe'. Bizzar example, I know! Anyway, with that set of conditions you would create the following object:

```
let unwantedFieldsFilter= { 
  userName: ['Mary', 'Joe'],    
  job: ['actor'],   
  language: ['English', 'Italian', 'Spanish', 'Greek']  
};
```

OK, now if you `ruleOut(actors, unwantedFieldsFilter)` you would only get

> [{userName: "Bill", job: "star", language: "Turkish"}]

And Bill is your man, since his name is not one of 'Mary', 'Joe', his nationality is not included in ['English', 'Italian', 'Spanish', 'Greek'] plus he is a Star!

There is one option in my method, that is `applyAllFilters` and is true by default.
If you would try to ruleOut with this param set as false, that would work as an 'OR' filtering instead of 'AND'. 
Example: `ruleOut(actors, {job:["actor"], language:["Italian"]}, false)` would get you everyone that is not an actor or Italian:

> [{userName: "Mary", job: "star", language: "Turkish"},
>   {userName: "Takis", job: "star", language: "Greek"},
>   {userName: "Joe", job: "star", language: "Turkish"},
>   {userName: "Bill", job: "star", language: "Turkish"}]